# SQLite in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, sqlite, applescript

I have a Windows app called via Shell  from MS Word that reads and writes to Sqlite. I'm porting it to Mac. On windows I have a batch file:

```
SQLite3.exe pathtodb\databasename <sqlitecommands.txt
```

This batch calls the Sqlite command line program, attachs the database, and reads the command from `sqlitecommands.txt`. The sqlitecommands is dynamically modified(by Word VBA) to read (Select) Write (Update) to/from the database.

What is the format of an applescript to do the same thing in Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

The following AppleScript creates a one-line shell script with sqlite syntax and executes it:

```
set sql to "sqlite3 ~/desktop/test.db 'insert into \"test\" values(\"hello world\",\"666\");'"
do shell script sql
```

You can use this example to create your own scripts dynamically.